# How to plot probability values from a list?

Tags: r, list, matlab, plot

I am trying to plot the results from a message passing loop.
I have stored the results using lists. I used two ways of doing so:

OUTSIDE THE LOOP

```
LIST1 <- list()

LIST2 <- vector("list", 16*2)
dim(LIST2) <- matrix(c(16,2))
```

INSIDE THE LOOP

```
LIST1[[paste(Ni, tau, sep="_")]] <- qs # store value for each iteration
LIST2[[Ni,tau]]<- qs #this is the updated approx posterior of the current iteration...
```

List1 looks something like this:
The loop had 16 iterations with 2 timesteps, resulting in 16x2 probability distributions

```
...
...
...
$`16_1`
           [,1]
[1,] 0.98780474
[2,] 0.01219526

$`16_2`
           [,1]
[1,] 0.98780474
[2,] 0.01219526
```

Now I tried several ways to get a resulting plot in R that looks like this from Matlab:

[image]

I have managed to transform the LIST2 into a data frame, but still wont plot.
The as.data.frame(LIST2) looks about like this:

```
       X15_1      X15_2      X16_1      X16_2
1 0.98780474 0.98780474 0.98780474 0.98780474
2 0.01219526 0.01219526 0.01219526 0.01219526
```

I often get errors like "figure margin too large", when I try "plot(LIST1), which
can not be resolved by zooming in, or exporting...

Comment: Can you just `unlist(LIST2)` and change the dimensions

Answer (score 0):

We can `unlist` the `list` and change the `dim`

```
`dim<-`(unlist(LIST_2), c(2, 4))
```